A priori knowledge vs. formalism
Mathematical truths are commonly used as an example of a priori knowledge in the Kantian sense. As a basic example, 2+2=4 is true regardless of anyones experience, it is true before any person writes it out or physically demonstrates it. I'm curious about the meaning behind that example.
In order to understand the meaning of 2+2=4, you must first define all of your terms, in which you arrive at just specifying arithmetic. But, then 2+2=4 is necessary in your theory just by the rules that you specified in your formalism. Is this saying anything interesting? You're just saying this is a specific theorem of a specific formalism. Does that mean that every theorem of a formal system is a priori knowledge?
One option I suppose is to define "2" as the action of counting (objects or symbols or concepts) one, and then two; "4" similarly, and "a+b" as counting "a" and then continuing to count "b". But I would argue that is still specifying a formalism.
If you try and represent it physically, by taking two sets of two apples and then using your hand to push them together into single pile. But what you did was just move matter around. You can intuitively distinguish discrete apples, but you still moved unit apples around. In order to extract any arithmetic meaning from it, you still have to specify what you mean by "2 apples" and "4 apples". You could just say "this pile is 2 apples" but then without arithmetic meaning, all you did is moved "2 apples" to the left.
Lastly, you can appeal to the intuitive concept that "2", "4", and "+" illicit and recognize that they correspond in "2+2=4". Is that the foundation of what we mean by a priori? Alternatively, are there any a priori truths that are not a result of formalism?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

It's instructive to read how educators actually teach children to count and to do simple sums, and how this teaching is interwoven with testing - you might be amazed by the complexity of the process. For instance: https://www.mav.vic.edu.au/Tenant/C0000019/00000001/downloads/Resources/Pearn_Counting_MAV_2017.pdf

2+2=4 can be seen both a priori knowledge and a theorem of a formal system.
From a "common number sense" (a priori knowledge?), many useful properties of numbers were found to be useful in real-world applications. The property that 2+2=4, for example, was found to be useful in commerce and trade.
Many of those properties were found to be derivable from other, previously established properties of numbers. It was discovered that many if not all known properties of numbers (including 2+2=4) could be formally derived from as few as five such properties (see Peano's Axioms).


“Mathematical truths are commonly used as an example of a priori
knowledge in the Kantian sense.”

In short and simplified:

Kant defines a priori knowledge as knowledge, which can be obtained
without any empiricism. There are two types of such knowledge:


Analytically a priori statement: Making explicit was is implicitly
contained in the statement. Example: Each bachelor is unmarried –
not very interesting. Analytical statements are always a priori. If one understands the words one can check whether the statement is true.

Synthetically a priori statement: A true
statement that cannot be checked just by analyzing the words of the statement. Nevertheless one does not need empirism to check its truth.



Kant considered all mathematical theorems as synthetically a priori.
Example: The sum of the angles of a plane triangle is 180 degrees.
Besides the mathematical theorems Kant considered also the basic
statements of Newtonian mechanics as synthetical a priori. Example:
Material objects have weight.
Kant’s main interest and achievement
in his work “Critique of pure Reason” is to identify synthetical a
priori statements within philosophy (metaphysics): The 12 basic
concepts (= categories) which the mind uses to process the input of
the senses after is has been preprocessed in the form of time and
space.

Today Kant’s conception is no longer generally accepted, several of his key claims on this field are outdated:



Mature mathematical theories can be axiomatized. Theorems of an axiomatized theory are analytic. The theorems make explicit what the definitions and axioms encapsulate. One needs the rules of logic to prove the theorem, not empiricism. See Snapper's survey Mathematical theorems analytic or synthetic?, and see also the comment below of @mudskipper.

The theorems of physical science are hypotheses, which
have to be confirmed or refuted by empiricism.

Kants synthetically a
priori of pure reason in the ontogenetic development is
explained as an posteriori from the phylogenetic development.



I do not think it's entirely correct to say that all mathematicians (or current philosophers of mathematics) consider mathematical theorems as "analytical a priori" statements in Kant's sense. I believe intuitionist/constructive mathematics would not accept this view. See for instance also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3649793/are-the-axioms-of-zfc-set-theory-considered-to-be-synthetic/3650984#3650984

@mudskipper Thanks, I expanded my answer.

You have a lacking understanding of the meaning of basic arithmetic. Run this python program on onecompiler.com:
x=int(input());
y=int(input());
print(x*y);

All it does is to multiply two input integers. Choose any 3 very large integers (e.g. 100 digits each) a,b,c, and use that program (4 times) to calculate both (a·b)·c and a·(b·c). If you are extra skeptical, use 4 separate computers, 1 for each multiplication. I claim that both results will be equal. Look carefully! I am making a claim about the real world, and moreover about arbitrary and gigantic integers, that you can choose so that they have never been recorded anywhere before. There is no sense in which the truth of this claim relies on some formal system. Rather, humans invented PA⁻ because they believed in such real-world truths and wanted to be able to deduce more truths based on these simpler ones. You being able to read this HTTPS webpage is in fact due to another arithmetical truth that can be proven in PA in a certain format.
You are correct that there must be some non-syntactic connection between our statements and the meaning we want them to represent. But you fail to see that it is not as nebulous as you think. The above program together with the python interpreter running on the server that hosts the website I gave you is one possible way to connect the formal statement "∀k,m,n ( (k·m)·n = k·(m·n) )" with the real world. Yes, it is impossible to be precise without relying on some shared knowledge, but that is not important now because programming languages have already provided a precise body of shared knowledge (that is way superior to talking about counting or apples or intuition).

I really don’t follow here. You’re making a claim about generalities of computer library implementations, but is that not simply a consequence of the schematic implementation of Python?  If you’re saying that Peano Arithmetic correctly applies to the Python schema, okay, but does that make the Python integers the integers?

@SofieSelnes: Have you actually tried following my instructions and running the given program to compute the multiplications shown? After you do it, think about why the results are equal. The python interpreter does not know what you are doing, and yet the results are equal. There is no such thing as "the integers". However, the people who developed the hardware and software that supports running python programs have implemented the multiplication operation to do something that people want with integers stored in memory (in whatever encoding format python uses). [cont]

[cont] That particular encoding used ties the abstract integers to the real world, and the truths about the operations defined on this encodings are solid real-world truths that do not depend on any formal systems. These truths can be captured by formal systems, but that's orthogonal.

" I claim that both results will be equal." Hm - this is an empirical prediction which may happen to come true (or not, since anything can happen -- a little hardware glitch and poof...) but I don't think mathematicians want to base any proofs on empirical predictions. It seems rather the reverse - the prediction itself is reliable, in sofar as the hardware and software are robust, and because the math is correct.

If we would merely use empirical predictions (plus induction or so) we could for instance never, even in principle, notice that a program had a software bug in the way it performed some calculation. I believe, we do expect the returned result to be identical each time - but that expectation itself can not be justified only by empirical knowledge.

@mudskipper: If you read what I said carefully, you would find that your objection doesn't apply to it. I didn't claim that no glitch could happen, but the certainty of the outcome facilitates demonstration of the undeniable connection between basic arithmetic as captured by PA⁻ and real-world computation. The problem is that many people do not want to face this fact of connection and grounding of this part of mathematics. Secondly, in your last comment you seem to suggest that PA⁻ is correct independently of empirical knowledge, but sorry there is no way to justify it apart from reality.

@user21820 - I think "Reality" and "real-world" are slippery words. "Certainty", "undeniable" likewise. If I would continue this discussion (which I don't really want to do now), I would start by denying that any of them have any clear meaning (or even a clear purpose) here ...

There's something very funny about making a mathematical argument using a program that cannot even correctly compute (0.1+0.1+0+1)

i guess as a less flippant reply: Python's division behavior has changed between py2 and py3. That seems like it really limits how seriously one should take its implementations of mathematical operations as proxies for "truth" or "real world computation"

@Kaia: I don't know whether to respond to your comments since you imply that they are flippant. But anyway.. Python is not computing "0.1+0.1+0.1" when you type that, and it would be foolish to think it does.. And I of course assume that the readers of my post had basic competency in logical reasoning and programming, which suffice to tell them that obviously they have to fix a language specification, say Python 3.. Finally, I never stated to take any implementation of mathematical operations as proxies for "truth" (about arithmetic), but you fail to provide any explanation for my predictions.
